# How to perform polynomial addition and multiplication using python 3.x?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples, polynomial-math

For instance, `3x^4 - 17x^2 - 3x + 5`.  Each term of the polynomial can be represented as a pair of integers (coefficient, exponent). i.e. `[(3,4),(-17,2), (-3,1), (5,0)]`

We have the following constraints to guarantee that each polynomial has a unique representation:

- Terms are sorted in descending order of exponent
- No term has a zero cofficient
- No two terms have the same exponent
- Exponents are always nonnegative

Write Python functions for the following operations:

```
addpoly(p1,p2)
multpoly(p1,p2)
```

Some examples:

```
>>> addpoly( [(4,3),(3,0)], [(-4,3),(2,1)] )
[(2, 1),(3, 0)]
```

Explanation: `(4x^3 + 3) + (-4x^3 + 2x) = 2x + 3`

```
>>> addpoly( [(2,1)], [(-2,1)] )
[]
```

Explanation: `2x + (-2x) = 0`

```
>>> multpoly( [(1,1),(-1,0)], [(1,2),(1,1),(1,0)] )
[(1, 3),(-1, 0)]
```

Explanation: `(x - 1) * (x^2 + x + 1) = x^3 - 1`

Comment: If you are allowed to use a library, just use sympy. No need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @user2341726: OP was asked for an implementation: "Write Python functions for `addpoly, multpoly`"

Answer (score 2):

You want to define a function that takes an arbitrary amount of arguments of the form

```
[(4,3),(3,0)], [(-4,3),(2,1)]
```

`addpoly` could be done easily with a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def addpoly(*polynoms):
    result = defaultdict(int)
    for polynom in polynoms:
        for factor, exponent in polynom:
            result[exponent] += factor
    return [(coeff, exponent) for exponent, coeff in result.items() if coeff]
```

```
In [68]: addpoly([(4,3),(3,0)],[(-4,3),(2,1)])
Out[68]: [(3, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: I just used floats because technically the exponents could be floats. If my answer answered your question, please accept it.

Comment: This code prints even those elements that have zero degree. instead we need a blank list. the compiler shows:
when input is 
addpoly([(4,3),(3,0)],[(-4,3),(2,1)])
Expected Output:
[(2, 1), (3, 0)]
Actual Output
[(0, 3), (1, 2), (3, 0)]

and in another case:
when input is addpoly([(2,1)],[(-2,1)])
Expected Output
[]
Actual Output
[(1, 0)]

Comment: I am really sorry for my frequent edits. I am new here :) thanks for your support!

Comment: I understand what to be done...but cant find a way to do it. Can you take a look at the 2nd comment and see how can we fix the output problem...

Comment: I amended my code to do it there is a `if factor `in the last line

Comment: If my answer answered your question please accept it.

Comment: Should be an accepted answer. What is a reason to use defaultdict? Will a simple dict work?